# node/npm - logging some stdout to file, some to console?

Tags: node.js, logging, npm

I have a script in my `package.json` that runs a function and logs to a JSON file.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "generate": "lib/utils/foo.ts > lib/utils/accounts/bar.json"
}
```

**lib/utils/foo.ts**

```
const runFoo = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const results = await otherFunction();
  // does a bunch of stuff
  // bunch of api calls and logging results using winston to the console

  console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
};

runFoo();
```

This works. It's great. However, it logs ALL stdout that get executed while the function runs, including all my winston logging.

What I would like is to log ONLY the final `console.log` to the `bar.json` file and have all my other winston logging instead be printed to the terminal.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

since you control the stdout output, you should know which line is the last line. when you know it, you can either print only it to stdout and redirect it to a file (similar like what you did) or print it to other stream and redirect only the specific stream.

another approach, will be tail'ing the last line. for instance

```sh
$ echo -e "first line\nsecond line" | tail -n -1
second line
```